# Вычисление выражений внутри нативных функций в Sass

Tags: css, веб-программирование, sass, scss

Есть такой отрывок из Sass стилей приложения:

```
calc(calc-column-width($columns) - $grid-gutters)
```

Проблема состоит в том, что на выходе Sass просто вставляет это выражение так как есть, не компилируя ни функцию, ни выражение. Функция внутри calc() возвращает величину в процентах. $grid-gutters содержит величину в пикселях. Есть ли какой нибудь вариант обойти это поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать интерполяцию Sass выражений:

```
calc(#{calc-column-width($columns)} - #{$grid-gutters})
```